# ¿Cómo resolver el error: InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: al llamar a un Store Procedure desde servicio con Spring Boot?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, stored-procedure

Tengo un servicio con Spring Boot que manda a llamar a un Store Procedure de Oracle, el SP se encuentra en SQL Developer en la ruta: **Paquetes -- > ELEMENT -- > SP_VALIDATE**

Tengo lo siguiente en mi Entidad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INCOMING")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Incoming.spValidate", procedureName = "ELEMENT.SP_VALIDATE", parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_guia", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_secuencia_numero", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_autorizacion, type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_transaccion", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "p_fecha", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "p_resultado", type = String.class) }),})
public class Incoming implements Serializable {

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUIA")
    private String guia;

    @Column(name = "SECUENCIA_NUMERO")
    private String secuenciaNum;

    @Column(name = "SEC_AUTORIACION")
    private String secAutorizacion;

    @Column(name = "SEC_TRANSACCION")
    private String secTransaccion

    @Column(name = "FECHA")
    private Date fecha;
```

y en mi repository

```
@Procedure(name = "Incoming.spValidate")
int spValidate(@Param("p_guia") String guia, @Param("p_secuencia_numero") String secuenciaNum,
        @Param("p_autorizacion") String secAutorizacion, @Param("p_transaccion") String secTransaccion,
        @Param("p_fecha") String fecha);
```

y el error que sale en el log es el siguiente:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'ELEMENT.SP_VALIDATE' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> "}
> {"app_timestamp" : "2021-09-27 18:25:42,018", "level" : "ERROR", "loggerName" : "s.c.c.GenericEmsErrorHandler:handleError:25", "msg" : "ErrorHandler, unmanaged exception description: Listener method 'public void com.prueba.consumidor.Consumidor.process(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [ELEMENT.SP_VALIDATE]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults. "}

alguien sabe a qué se debe este error? que puede estar mal?

El STORE PROCEDURE es

```html
create or replace package                   ELEMENT as
procedure SP_VALIDATE(
P_GUIA IN VARCHAR2,
P_SECUENCIA_NUMERO IN VARCHAR2,
P_SEC_AUTORIZACION IN VARCHAR2,
P_SEC_TRANSACCION IN VARCHAR2,
P_FECHA IN VARCHAR2,
P_RESULTADO OUT NUMBER);
```

Comment: intentaste mandarlo sin el `;`?

Comment: Veo varios errores, el primero en la linea ` "p_autorizacion, type = String.class),` falta unas comillas dobles, y los nombres `p_autorizacion`, `p_transaccion` no coinciden con los nombres de los campos en el store procedure.